# Build Android Source on Mac OSX 10.9

Tags: macos, android-source

I am trying to build Android source code https://source.android.com/source/building-running.html on Mac OS X 10.9.2, and with Command Line Developer Tools version is 5.1

While building I am getting this error:

```
host C++: v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_arm64_arm64_host_gyp <= external/chromium_org/v8/src/accessors.cc
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-unused-local-typedefs"
build/core/binary.mk:583: recipe for target 'out/host/darwin-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/v8_tools_gyp_v8_base_arm64_arm64_host_gyp_intermediates/v8/src/accessors.o' failed
```

How to get this compiler option `Wno-unused-local-typedefs`? or get around this option?

I am planning to install GCC 4.8 or above through mac port, and refer to this GCC, let me know if you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2510898.

There are some changes needed in the build makefiles for build to work on Darwin. The last section in the guide above. That could be the reason. Look at this patch:
https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_external_chromium_org/commit/5130af630390487b37d99941887883647c67f37a

Hope this helps.